# Why's my Auth check in Laravel passport always returning false when trying to logout even though I can successfully register?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm able to register successfully which should imply that the user's authenticated but it turns out that's not the case for some reason.

Upon trying to logout on the frontend:

When running `dd(Auth::check());` - it always returns  `false` when it's OUTSIDE of the `middleware('auth:api');`.

However, when running `dd(Auth::check());` - it always returns `{message: "Unauthenticated."}` when it's INSIDE of the `middleware('auth:api');`.

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [RegisterController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

RegisterController.php:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    $headers = collect($request->header())->transform(function ($item) {
        return $item[0];
    });

    $success['cookie'] = 'Bearer' . $headers['cookie'];
    $success['content-type'] = $headers['content-type'];
    $success['authenticated'] = Auth::check();

    dd(Auth::check());

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully logged out',
        'cookie' => $success['cookie'],
        'content-type' => $success['content-type'],
        'authenticated' => $success['authenticated']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `Auth::guard('api')->check()`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi yeah just tried it.  I'm getting the same exact results as mentioned in my original post :(.

Comment: The middleware should be kicking in and that dd invalid, maybe a config? also if `'Bearer' . $headers['cookie'];` is for the token? it should be in `Authorization` header and 'Bearer '

Comment: I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69335246/whys-authcheck-returning-false-even-though-im-logging-in-successfully) which asked same question and it solved my issue :)